# Using nuxt.js auth with multiple app in the same PC

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two apps using auth module and nuxt.js running in my PC .
I am used auth local strategies at both app.

I have a problem when  I am logged(authenticated) in my first app, the second app  doesn´t  ask for authentication(both apps in same PC).

I have to delete the localstorage with auth data, in order to my second app ask for login to authenticate.

My nuxt auth settings is in the nuxt.config.js is:

```
auth: {
    localStorage: {
      prefix: 'auth.',
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: 'refresh',
        token: {
          property: 'data.access_token',
          maxAge: 1800,

          type: 'Bearer',
          required: true,
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'data.refresh_token',
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        },
        user: {
          property: 'data',
          autoFetch: true,
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: 'user/login',
            method: 'post',
          },
          refresh: { url: 'user/refreshToken', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: 'user/me', method: 'get' },
          logout: false,
        },
      },
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/login',
      // callback: '/dash',
      // home: '/clientes',
      home: '/',
    },
  },
```

Is there some special settings in the config to avoid it
I have tried to use a different localstore prefix, but no look

Comment: Both of them authorize using the same back-end API?

Comment: @bar5um Yes, it is.

Comment: I think the easiest way to prevent this is to run apps on different ports using server property: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-server/#basic-example

Comment: One token is working for the second website? How is that a thing? You should have a check on the backend to only allow a single session per app. Otherwise, changing the port or using a different browser is also a decent solution indeed.

Comment: @kissu  Sorry, but I am using jwt. I´m not using session on server side

Comment: @bar5um  Sorry but I guess it will not be solve my problem. I did a test with the first app runing in a remote server. From my PC If I authenticate in that app then my second app running in my dev PC doesn´t ask for authentication.  It happends because auth module is saving the auth  data in the localstorage and the second app is using this same data to checking if is authenticated.

Comment: By "session" I meant "one user connected at the same time with the same credentials" not an actual session because we are in a front-end only context here. You should not use localStorage anyway. Then, your backend should check the token and allow your user. There is a low probability that you have the same exact matching token, or at least you should have it setup someway like that.

Answer (score 1):

NuxtJs has localStorage enabled by default as a session persistence engine.

```js
auth: {
  localStorage: {
    prefix: 'auth.'
  }
}
```

You need to provide a different prefix in your localStorage configuration (of course, if you intend to continue using localStorage) for each of your projects. That should make sure both apps don't look for the session token in the same key.

This is what you're looking for
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options/#localstorage

There's an option for cookies as well, but the logic remains the same.

Comment: Don't use localStorage, cookies are safer.